# Web API: Action Filter gets ClientId given ApiKey, but how to get ClientID in Controller classes?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API service that passes in an ApiKey with the request header. A custom action filter (AuthenticationRequiredAttribute) derived from ActionFilterAttribute overrides the OnActionExecuting method and does a DB call to get the ClientId associated with a valid ApiKey. I can assign the ClientID as a property via `HttpActionContext.Request.Properties.Add ("clientID", clientID)`, but then I cannot access the associated actionContext object in the controller action method, so it is of no value.

Surely this is a common situation, but I cannot find an good example dealing with it. How do I get the HttpActionContext instance into the controller class?

Here is the filter:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
```

Within this, I get the ClientID, but I don't see how to pass it to the method below:

Here is the Controller's method:

```
[Route("v1/stock/{SecurityId}/text")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetSummaryTextV1(string SecurityId, string topic = "")
```

The HttpActionContext is not available within. I need ClientID in here, but cannot get it.

Is there a way that I can pass the current actionContext into the Controller constructor?

At a loss, hard-wiring the clientId for now, so I can proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy solution to this problem. Rather than use a custom 'AuthenticationRequired' attribute derived from the ActionFilterAttribute class and specified in global.asax:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new AuthenticationRequiredAttribute());

public class AuthenticationRequiredAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        /* My authentication and lookup logic here */
    }
}
```

I simply put the logic in a new Controller constructor with fields whose values are filled on successful authentication. It is simple and straight-forward. No HttpActionContext.Request.Properties.Add gobbledygook, no resurrecting the session object, just fields and a constructor. Duh. That being said, I do appreciate the two suggestions I received; I just was not able to implement them.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/basic-authentication-with-asp-net-webapi/

I have implemented this approach.  Once the caller is authenticated, I store their client id in a custom `IIdentity` that I then use inside the controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Request.Properties` to access the properties.

EDIT:

You can set the CliendID in the properties like you have in your question

```
HttpActionContext.Request.Properties.Add ("clientID", clientID)
```

and access the properties in your controller using `Request.Properties`

Comment: Hiya - I don't know if this answers the question or not (this is not my are of expertise), but this answer is pretty short, so it ended up on the "low quality posts" review queue. Perhaps you could provide a bit more explanation about this, so we can tell either way?

Comment: At best it's half an answer